# .apk file upload error

Tags: android

When i upload my .apk file it gives this error

The certificate that signed this apk is not valid until the future. Create a new certificate.

Thanks

Comment: i have the same problem but i created the key some minutes ago... also the second came with this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Problem! 
And my system time was in the futur! So i only need to wait some minutes

Answer (score 1):

Create a new certificate/sign key, your old one has probably expired (when creating a key, you can usually set it's expiration date).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html how to create your own key other than the default debug key.

Answer (score 0):

make a keystore that has more than 20 years validity ..say 100 years
it will do the rest..

Answer (score 0):

just wait for some time after creating your apk and then try to upload it. then the error wont appear.